# Knowing the sum, the n(), and the bound parameters of a truncated-Pareto distributed variable, how I identify the alpha (shape) parameter?

Tags: pareto-distribution, truncated-distributions

I know that there would be a fancy command on `R` to do the estimation of $\alpha$ given the inputs, but I am also curious about the relationship between $\alpha$ to $\mathbb{E}(\sum (x))$, given $n(x)$, $min(x)$ and $max(x)$.

Also, given that observed $\hat{max(x)} \leq max(x)$, is there a way to estimate $\alpha$ without bias? I know that in applied science, Pareto estimation is actually very hard, but I don't know about truncated Pareto.

I accept suggestion on the best way to estimate it in `R`. I know truncated/bounded Paretos are in `VGAM`, but I don't know the commands to model Pareto distribution. Is it correct to use the package `fitdistrplus`?

Comment: There is no stable sum for $\alpha\leq 1$ for the Pareto distribution type I. There is a stable sum for $\alpha>1$. If you want a measure that is always stable, use the harmonic mean for that distribution.

Comment: @Carl: All the same, a *truncated* Pareto distribution will have a finite expectation for any value of $\alpha$. For inference on $\alpha$, truncation notwithstanding, the geometric mean is a minimal sufficient statistic; the harmonic mean isn't. (And if only the sample sum is available then neither are calculable from it.)

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I found the question to be ambiguous because all Pareto distributions of types I through IV are left truncated power functions. It would help to specify "right truncated" if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @Carl: Could be clearer, but the upper bound is mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica [For the case of the Pareto type I distribution](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/09/the-long-tail-of-the-pareto-distribution/), the reciprocal transformation converts it into the extremely well-behaved beta distribution, and the harmonic mean has the following simple expression:

            Harmonic mean = $k(1 + a^{-1})$

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Also, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/271126/99274.

Comment: @Carl: That's nice but doesn't make the harmonic mean the best choice of statistic on which to base an estimator of $\alpha$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133977/discussion-between-carl-and-scortchi-reinstate-monica).

Comment: Suggested reading, von Hippel et al. arxiv.org/pdf/1402.4061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's well known that $\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i$ is complete & minimal sufficient for the shape parameter $\alpha$ of an untruncated Pareto distribution—& truncation doesn't affect the completeness or sufficiency of a statistic (Smith, 1957). Consequently (1) you ought to be basing an estimator on the sum of logged observations (or the sample geometric mean, or an equivalent), & (2) you'll be lucky to find an estimator based on the sum of observations (or the sample arithmetic mean, or an equivalent), either derived in papers or textbooks, or implemented in software libraries.

If you do have the full sample,  or $\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i$, Aban et al. (2006) derive the score function for $\alpha$, which you can find the root of to give its maximum-likelihood estimate (for the cases of both known & unknown bounds<sup>†</sup>), & show that its distribution is asymptotically Gaussian (you can get standard error estimates from the gradient at the root). (They also cite a paper deriving the uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator.)

If for some reason all you have to work with is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, then you could try a method-of-moments approach to estimating $\alpha$. Note the arithmetic mean exists for all $\alpha>0$, unlike the case of an untruncated Pareto distribution—see [Do all bounded probability distributions have a definite mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/442265/17230). Given a Pareto distribution with density

$$
f(x)= \frac{\alpha \beta^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}
$$

its expectation when truncated above at $\tau$ is

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E} X | X < \tau &= \frac{\int^\tau x f(x)\ \mathrm{d} x}{\int^\tau f(x) \ \operatorname{d} x} \\
&= \frac{\int_\beta^\tau x^{-\alpha}\ \mathrm{d}x}
{\int_\beta^\tau x^{-(\alpha+1)}\ \mathrm{d}x}\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\cdot\frac{[x^{1-\alpha}]^\tau_\beta}{[x^\alpha]^\tau_\beta}\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\cdot\frac{\tau^{1-\alpha} - \beta^{1-\alpha}}{\tau^{-\alpha}-\beta^{-\alpha}}\\
&= \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-1}\cdot\frac{1 - \left(\frac{\beta}{\tau}\right)^{\alpha-1}}{1-\left(\frac{\beta}{\tau}\right)^{\alpha}}\\
\end{align}
$$

So plug in the sample mean $\bar x$ for $\operatorname{E} X$, & $\hat\alpha$ for $\alpha$, & find the root for $\hat\alpha$ numerically.<sup>‡</sup> (You could bootstrap to get confidence interval/standard error/bias estimates.)

---

```
# function to generate Pareto variates
rpareto <- function(n, alpha, beta) beta/(1-runif(n))^(1/alpha)

# function to calculate expectation
EX <- Vectorize(function(alpha, beta, tau, epsilon = 1e-7){
  if (abs(alpha-1) > epsilon){
    (alpha*beta/(alpha-1)) * (1 - (beta/tau)^(alpha-1)) / (1 - (beta/tau)^alpha)
  }
  else {
    alpha*beta*log(tau/beta) / (1 - (beta/tau)^alpha)
  }
})

# function that you'll find the root of
f <- function(alpha, x.bar, beta, tau, epsilon = 1e-7) {
  x.bar - EX(alpha, beta, tau, epsilon = 1e-7)
}

alpha_0 <- 2 # true value of alpha
beta <- 3
tau <- 9

# make up some data
set.seed(1234)
x <- rpareto(200, alpha_0, beta)
x <- x[x < tau]
length(x)
plot(ecdf(x), verticals=TRUE, pch="")

# find sample mean
(x.bar <- mean(x))

# find roughly where alpha.hat lies
alpha <- seq(1, 3, by=0.1)
plot(alpha, EX(alpha, beta, tau), type="l", ylab="EX")
abline(h = x.bar, lty=2)

# calculate alpha.hat
(alpha.hat <- uniroot(f, x.bar=x.bar, beta = beta, tau = tau, lower = 2, upper = 3)$root)
```

---

† With regard to the question in your 2nd paragraph: as you know the bound parameters, the sample minimum & maximum don't enter into the estimation of $\alpha$. If you didn't know the bound parameters, the sample minimum & maximum are their M.L.E.s., & you can substitute them for the known bound parameters in the score equation for $\alpha$ (what changes is the standard errors you'd calculate for the M.L.E. of $\alpha$).

---

‡ Note
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 1} \frac{1-\left(\frac{\beta}{\tau}\right)^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1} = \log \frac{\tau}{\beta}$$

for when $\alpha \approx 1$ in numerical calculations.

---

[Aban et al. (2006), "Parameter Estimation for the Truncated Pareto Distribution", *J. Am. Stat. Assoc.*, **101**, 473](https://doi.org/10.1198/016214505000000411)

[Smith (1957), "A Note on Truncation and Sufficient Statistics", *Ann. Math. Statist.*, **28**, 1](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177707049)

Comment: The problem is that when $\alpha<1$ the [mean is undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Moments_and_characteristic_function), and the geometric mean is [not as well behaved as the harmonic mean](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.4061) in that case. If this truly is [right truncated then a mean exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Bounded_Pareto_distribution).

Comment: @Carl: I'm afraid you've thoroughly misunderstood the paper you link to. At no point do Hippel et al. even discuss using the sample harmonic mean to estimate $\alpha$. The geometric mean of an i.i.d. sample from a truncated or non-truncated Pareto distribution is complete & sufficient for $\alpha$, so best estimators will be functions of it alone (given any convex loss function).

Comment: OK, you are correct and wrong for a particular context in which one has a Pareto type I density function obtained from non-i.i.d. conditions. That is, if one already has a Pareto distribution density function, to obtain a geometric mean one would have to infinitely resample the density function to create i.i.d. conditions, and find a correct [lowest non-zero value](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399292/373043). Baring that, the harmonic mean proceeds directly from the density function, making such an inventive procedure unnecessary.

Comment: @Carl: I couldn't make head or tail of that - do you perhaps have a reference? The post you link to merely describes maximum-likelihood estimation of both lower bound & shape parameters from an i.i.d. sample from an untruncated Pareto distribution.

Comment: OK, ignore the upper truncated case for the moment. How do you propose to calculate the geometric mean of $$
f(x)= \frac{\alpha \beta^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}\;,
$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known?

Comment: @Carl: $\beta \exp{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$

Comment: I see. So $\beta=x_m$ from the [characterization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#A_characterization_theorem), which in turn assumes that the density function arose from random variate $x$-values, even when it does not. That is, not all density functions relate to probability or random variates. I wonder if there is a better way of establishing the geo mean for other circumstances.

Comment: @Carl: The geometric mean's simply $\exp \int_\beta^\infty \log x f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ where $f(x)$ is the Pareto density. The characterization theorem you reference has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I wanted to know.